# Unable to store value of fgetc()

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that takes in 2 matrices from text files and then multiplies them together.  They will always be able to be multiplied.  I am having an issue storing the data that I take in from my matrix.  I am very new to C and the IDE I am using is throwing no errors but the program does not run.  I have deduced that it is because I am trying to store `int c` into `a[i]` but I am not sure why.

I have tried changing types of the array and of c but none of these seem to be the problem.

```
int main()
{
FILE *matrixA;
FILE *matrixB;
int a[8];
int b[8];
int i;
int j;

matrixA = fopen("matrixA.txt", "r");
matrixB = fopen("matrixB.txt", "r");

while(1) {
  int c = fgetc(matrixA);
  a[i] = c;
  if( feof(matrixA) ) {
     break;
  }
  printf("%c", c);
  i++;
}

printf("\n");
printf("A %c", a[0]);
printf("\n");

while(1) {
  int c = fgetc(matrixB);
  b[j] = c;
  if( feof(matrixB) ) {
     break;
  }
  printf("%c", c);
  j++;
}
printf("B %c", b[0]);
```

The only error message I get is that the main returns -1029219.
The matrices come in as "1 2 3 4\n8 7 6 5".  Currently I do not test for white space but I will once I am able to figure out how to pass in values to a[] and b[].  Thanks

Comment: `c` is a character code, not a number created by parsing the text file. You should probably be using `fscanf()`.

Comment: You don't have a return statement so the return value is just random data from the stack.

Comment: j and I are never initialized.  You'll want to set both to 0 when you define them.  What warnings do you get when you compile?  Those should be cleaned up first.

Comment: No warnings from compiler, also the compiler auto initializes i,j to 0.  Definitely bad practice to leave it that way.  Thanks.  @Barmar going to try to use fscanf() now.  Wouldn't I still be able to store the character code though?

Comment: I'm curious, what compiler initializes local variables to 0?  I've worked with many different compilers and have never seen this.

Comment: GNU GCC Compiler.  It came with the CodeBlocks IDE

Comment: @Kevin If they're 0 it's just random luck, not intentional.

Comment: @Kevin Why would you want to store the character code? Don't you want to store the number that it represents? Also, if you have multiple-digit numbers, your code will just store one digit at a time, it won't parse the whole number like `scanf()` would. And `scanf()` will also skip over whitespace.

Comment: I do want to store the actual integer.  I did not know that fgetc() got the character code instead of the integer.  Working on using fscanf() to get the actual values and not the character codes currently.

Comment: @Kevin I just tried with gcc on my machine and it doesn't initialize the variables.  However, by default gcc does not return a warning which surprised me.  I had to turn on all warnings with the -Wall options.

Comment: @jmq Interesting, it appears I am just very lucky then.  Fixed it regardless thanks for the catch.

Comment: @barmar if you could show a basic implementation of scanf() I would appreciate it.  I am having trouble getting it to work properly.

Comment: @user207421 The initial problem I had was that I was not able to store the parsed value from fgetc().  This was because I was mismatching types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't read a character at a time, use `fscanf()` to read whole integers from the file. It will parse the numbers and skip over whitespace between them.

```
int i = 0;
while(fscanf(matrixA, "%d", &a[i]) == 1) {
  printf("%d ", a[i]);
  i++;
}
printf("\n");
```